# how to get oldest month data using datetime column in spark dataframe(Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe which has two column one is id and secound id col_datetime. as you can see the dataframe given below. how can i filter the dataframe based on col_datetime to get the oldest month data. I want to achieve the result dynamically because I have 20 odd dataframes.

```
INPUT DF:-

   import spark.implicits._
val data = Seq((1 , "2020-07-02 00:00:00.0"),(2 , "2020-08-02 00:00:00.0"),(3 , "2020-09-02 00:00:00.0"),(4 , "2020-10-02 00:00:00.0"),(5 , "2020-11-02 00:00:00.0"),(6 , "2020-12-02 00:00:00.0"),(7 , "2021-01-02 00:00:00.0"),(8 , "2021-02-02 00:00:00.0"),(9 , "2021-03-02 00:00:00.0"),(10, "2021-04-02 00:00:00.0"),(11, "2021-05-02 00:00:00.0"),(12, "2021-06-02 00:00:00.0"),(13, "2021-07-22 00:00:00.0"))
val dfFromData1 = data.toDF("ID","COL_DATETIME").withColumn("COL_DATETIME",to_timestamp(col("COL_DATETIME")))

+------+---------------------+
|ID    |COL_DATETIME         |
+------+---------------------+
|1     |2020-07-02 00:00:00.0|
|2     |2020-08-02 00:00:00.0|
|3     |2020-09-02 00:00:00.0|
|4     |2020-10-02 00:00:00.0|
|5     |2020-11-02 00:00:00.0|
|6     |2020-12-02 00:00:00.0|
|7     |2021-01-02 00:00:00.0|
|8     |2021-02-02 00:00:00.0|
|9     |2021-03-02 00:00:00.0|
|10    |2021-04-02 00:00:00.0|
|11    |2021-05-02 00:00:00.0|
|12    |2021-06-02 00:00:00.0|
|13    |2021-07-22 00:00:00.0|
+------+---------------------+

OUTPUT:-

DF1 : - Oldest month data
+------+---------------------+
|ID    |COL_DATETIME         |
+------+---------------------+
|1     |2020-07-02 00:00:00.0|
+------+---------------------+

DF2:- lastest months data after removing oldest month data from orginal DF.

+------+---------------------+
|ID    |COL_DATETIME         |
+------+---------------------+
|2     |2020-08-02 00:00:00.0|
|3     |2020-09-02 00:00:00.0|
|4     |2020-10-02 00:00:00.0|
|5     |2020-11-02 00:00:00.0|
|6     |2020-12-02 00:00:00.0|
|7     |2021-01-02 00:00:00.0|
|8     |2021-02-02 00:00:00.0|
|9     |2021-03-02 00:00:00.0|
|10    |2021-04-02 00:00:00.0|
|11    |2021-05-02 00:00:00.0|
|12    |2021-06-02 00:00:00.0|
|13    |2021-07-22 00:00:00.0|
+------+---------------------+
```

logic/approach:-

**step1** :- calculate the minimum datetime for col_datetime column for given dataframe and assign to mindate variable.
Lets assume I will get

```
var mindate = "2020-07-02 00:00:00.0" 

val mindate = dfFromData1.select(min("COL_DATETIME")).first()
print(mindate)

result:- 
mindate : org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [2020-07-02 00:00:00.0]
[2020-07-02 00:00:00.0]
```

**Step2**:- to get the end date of month using mindate.I haven’t code for this part to get enddatemonth using mindate.

```
Val enddatemonth = "2020-07-31 00:00:00.0"
```

**Step3** : - Now I can use enddatemonth variable to filter the spark dataframe in DF1 and DF2 based on conditions.
Even if I tried to filter the dataframe based on mindate I am getting error

```
val DF1 = dfFromData1.where(col("COL_DATETIME") <= enddatemonth)
val DF2 = dfFromData1.where(col("COL_DATETIME") > enddatemonth)

Error : <console>:166: error: type mismatch; 
found : org.apache.spark.sql.Row 
required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column val DF1 = dfFromData1.where(col("COL_DATETIME" )<= mindate)
```

Thanks...!!

Comment: Do you understand the error message?  It says that `mindate` you've calculated is a row, not a column. The row has only one column, but you still need to unwrap it, get out the value. I won't tell you how, I don't know spark.

Comment: Yes i got your point, even i dont have expertise in spark and dont know to how to convert  row into column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Similar approach , but I find it cleaner just to deal with MONTHS.

Idea : like we have epoch for seconds, compute it for months

```
val dfWithEpochMonth = dfFromData1.
                       withColumn("year",year($"COL_DATETIME")).
                       withColumn("month",month($"COL_DATETIME")).
                       withColumn("epochMonth", (($"year" - 1970 - 1) * 12) + $"month")
```

Now your df will look like :

```
+---+-------------------+----+-----+----------+
| ID|       COL_DATETIME|year|month|epochMonth|
+---+-------------------+----+-----+----------+
|  1|2020-07-02 00:00:00|2020|    7|       595|
|  2|2020-08-02 00:00:00|2020|    8|       596|
|  3|2020-09-02 00:00:00|2020|    9|       597|
|  4|2020-10-02 00:00:00|2020|   10|       598|
```

Now, you can calculate min epochMonth and filter directly.

```
val minEpochMonth = dfWithEpochMonth.select(min("epochMonth")).first().apply(0).toString().toInt

val df1 = dfWithEpochMonth.where($"epochMonth" <= minEpochMonth)
val df2 = dfWithEpochMonth.where($"epochMonth" > minEpochMonth)
```

You can drop unnecessary columns.

---

To address your error message :

```
val mindate = dfFromData1.select(min("COL_DATETIME")).first()
val mindateString = mindate.apply(0).toString()
```

Now you can use mindateString to filter.

Comment: Thanks...how can i solve the .row to .column so that my solution works?

Comment: added the workaround for your Error message.

Comment: Thanks it works. additionally if i want to calculate last day of month using mindate then convert it into string and used for filter in next step? how can i do that?

Comment: I do not think any time library provides this direct function. But, you could do something like..  mindate ->setHour(0) , setMin(0), setSec(0) , setDate(1); and then mindate setMonth(currentMonth + 1 ). Again check if `currentMonth + 1 ` is more than 12 n all. 
Better to Avoid all these error prone calculate and validattions.